# How do I replace a burnt atmega328 with a new atmega328(bootloaded) in arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328

I have an arduino UNO with atmega 328 whose microcontroller got burnt. I bought a new atmega328. I have another working arduino with atmega8. I followed the instructions in http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard but I got a little confused.

I burnt the bootloader into my new atmega328 using atmega8 arduino as described in the link above. Now, can I replace my old atmega328 with this new bootloaded atmega328 to upload sketches to it? Or should I follow the steps described in the link to upload sketches?

Answer (score 3):

Once the bootloader has been burned to it, the chip can replace the one that is currently on the Arduino board. Simply follow normal DIP removal and insertion procedures to replace it.